# If array contains a id displaying other fields of that id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Controller:

```
  $games=Game::all();
  $results=Result::get()->toArray();
  $check=NULL;
  if(is_array($results))
    {
        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            $check[]=$result['game_id'];
        }
     }
  return view('index')>with(['games'=>$games,'check'=>$check]);
```

`results` tabel (Result model) contains `id, game_id, won_by` 
I've checked if the game_id is contained in results table or not. If yes i want to display the `won_by` field of that `game_id`.

```
<?php
foreach($games as $game)
{
     if(is_array($check) && in_array($game->id,$check))
     {
            echo "Won by"; 
     }
...
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @u_mulder I want to display won_by field of that game_id in results table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the relationship between `Game` and `Result`.

```
class Game extends Eloquent 
{
    public function result()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Result::class);
    }
}
```

Then, load the games with the results.

```
$games = Game::with('result')->all();
```

Then you can loop through them in the view. If they have a result, you know they were won.

```
@foreach ($games as $game)
    @if ($game->result)
        Game won by {{ $game->result->won_by }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```